Detatch/edit type created when using the dimension tool in illustrator
Is there a way to disconnect the type when using the dimension tool? I tried to ungroup and unmask and using the direct selection tool but it doesn't want to detatch. I'm finding it difficult to edit the text instead of selecting it just creates a new text box.


There are two methods I know of:

Do Object > Expand Appearance, then you can edit the text, or ungroup it, and edit as you want

or

With the Selection Tool V, move the dimension object. Then everything will become editable as with method 1.

Note that these are both destructive and the dimension object will no longer be functional. So for example, if if the dimension is linked to an object and you do either of the above, then if you edit the object, the dimension will no longer update automatically.
If your goal here is to edit the measurement text because you are working to a scale other than 1:1 - neither of the above are particularly efficient. I would avoid them if possible. Instead, if you double click the Dimension tool, you can bring up the Dimension Tool Options, and you can change the scale in there.
